# New record in Bindingsource

Tags: .net, bindingsource

I have a form with a datagridview and some text boxes which is bind to the bindingsource. There are an New button and Save button on the form. I wanted the user to

1. click the New button that will cause grid to go to a new row and the textboxes to go blank (since it is a new row).
2. Next, the user will enter data into the textboxes to for a new record
3. Finally click Save button to save the record and update to database

I have no idea on the code for the Add and Save buttons.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

This tutorial will give you a detailed overview of what your wanting to do.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial